# Gallery (picture shower)

Tags: html, css

I'm making a Gallery page on my web site (project) and I've put `<a target="_blank"`but I don't like It :P. So I've remembered on some sites there is like pop-up window with picture and when you click on left or right side of the picture it slides to the next or previous picture. Best way to explain it is showing you [LINK](http://gameinfo.eune.leagueoflegends.com/en/game-info/champions/brand/). Thanks in advance.

**EDIT** Click on those pictures under the **Skins**!!!!

```css
body {
  background-image: url("https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/originals/e4/98/1a/e4981a3dd4aa2fa6f0bc84cde9087c7a.jpg");
  background-attachment: fixed;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin-left: 20px;
  margin-right: 20px;
  margin-top: 0px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  border-top-left-radius: 25px;
  border-top-right-radius: 25px;
  border-right: solid rgb(200, 101, 103);
  border-left: solid rgb(200, 101, 103);
  border-bottom-left-radius: 25px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 25px;
}

#header {
  height: 50px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: auto;
}

#navigacija {
  right: 20px;
  left: 20px;
  height: 50px;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-align: right;
  background-color: #089DE3;
  z-index: 9999;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-radius: 25px;
  position: fixed;
  border-top: solid rgb(200, 101, 103);
  border-bottom: solid rgb(200, 101, 103);
}

.navitem {
  background: #089DE3;
  color: white;
  line-height: 50px;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-family: "Fjalla One";
  display: inline-block;
  padding-left: 50px;
  padding-right: 50px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.home:hover {
  background: #00C5CD;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.gallery:hover {
  background: #00C5CD;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.contact:hover {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background: #00C5CD;
}

.info:hover {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background: #00C5CD;
}

.active {
 background-color: #00C5CD;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

h1 {
 text-align: center;
 font-family: "Jockey One";
 font-size: 100px;
 color: white;
}
div.galerija {
 margin-left: 10px;
 margin-right:32px;
 margin-bottom:10px;
 border: 1px solid rgb(200, 101, 103);
 float: left;
 width: 300px;
}
div.galerija:hover {
 border: 1px solid white;
}

div.desc {
 padding: 10px;
 text-align: center;
 color: black;
 background-color: white;
 font-size: 20px;
 font-family:"Jockey One";
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
 
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en" xml:lang="en">

<head>

<meta name="generator" content="HTML Tidy for Linux (vers 25 March 2009), see www.w3.org" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
<title>GALLERY</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="Gallery.css" type="text/css" />
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Jockey+One" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Allerta+Stencil" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Fjalla+One" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

</head>

<body>


  <div id="header">
    <div id="navigacija">
      <a href="Home.html">
        <div class="navitem home"><strong>HOME</strong></div>
      </a>
      <a href="Gallery.html">
      <div class="navitem gallery active"><strong>GALLERY</strong></div></a>
      <a href="#"></a>
      <div class="navitem contact"><strong>CONTACT</strong></div>
      <a href="#"></a>
      <div class="navitem info"><strong>INFO</strong></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <h1><strong>GALLERY</strong></h1>
  
  <div class="galerija">
  <a target="_blank" href="http://www.downvids.net/video/bestimages/img-aatrox-the-darkin-blade-196.jpg">
  <img src="http://www.downvids.net/video/bestimages/img-aatrox-the-darkin-blade-196.jpg" alt="Aatrox" width="300" height="200">
  </a>
  <div class="desc">Aatrox, the Darkin Blade</div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="galerija">
  <a target="_blank" href="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/xE4e_cLMgjU/maxresdefault.jpg">
  <img src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/xE4e_cLMgjU/maxresdefault.jpg" alt="Ahri" width="300" height="200"></a>
  <div class="desc">Ahri, the Nine-Tailed Fox</div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="galerija">
  <a target="_blank" href= "https://cdn.tryhardgopro.com/static/ddragon/cdn/img/champion/splash/Akali_0.jpg ">
  <img src="https://cdn.tryhardgopro.com/static/ddragon/cdn/img/champion/splash/Akali_0.jpg " alt="Akali" width="300" height="200"></a>
  <div class="desc">Akali, the Fist of Shadow</div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="galerija">
  <a target="_blank" href="http://ddragon.leagueoflegends.com/cdn/img/champion/splash/Alistar_0.jpg">
  <img src="http://ddragon.leagueoflegends.com/cdn/img/champion/splash/Alistar_0.jpg" alt="Alistar" width="300" height="200"></a>
  <div class="desc">Alistar, the Minotaur</div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="galerija">
  <a target="_blank" href="https://cdn.tryhardgopro.com/static/ddragon/cdn/img/champion/splash/Amumu_0.jpg">
  <img src="https://cdn.tryhardgopro.com/static/ddragon/cdn/img/champion/splash/Amumu_0.jpg" alt="Amumu" width="300" height="200"></a>
  <div class="desc">Amumu, the Sad Mummy</div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="galerija">
  <a target="_blank" href="http://static.lolskill.net/img/skins/1215/anivia_0.jpg">
  <img src="http://static.lolskill.net/img/skins/1215/anivia_0.jpg " alt="Anivia" width="300" height="200"></a>
  <div class="desc">Anivia, the Cryophoenix</div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="galerija">
  <a target="_blank" href="http://media-titanium.cursecdn.com/loldiffs/AirClientDiff_1_28_2013_2_28_PM/images/Annie_Splash_0.jpg">
  <img src="http://media-titanium.cursecdn.com/loldiffs/AirClientDiff_1_28_2013_2_28_PM/images/Annie_Splash_0.jpg" alt="Annie" width="300" height="200"></a>
  <div class="desc">Annie, the Dark Child</div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="galerija">
  <a target="_blank" href="http://images2.wikia.nocookie.net/__cb20101005190542/leagueoflegends/images/c/c0/Ashe_OriginalSkin.jpg">
  <img src="http://images2.wikia.nocookie.net/__cb20101005190542/leagueoflegends/images/c/c0/Ashe_OriginalSkin.jpg" alt="Ashe" width="300" height="200"></a>
  <div class="desc">Ashe, the Frost Archer</div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="galerija">
  <a target="_blank" href="http://s.lolstatic.com/site/mount-targon/079694fdf251b5e7de788d9ab439d401d31ae160/img/champions/aurelion-sol/aurelion-sol-splash-fallback.jpg">
  <img src="http://s.lolstatic.com/site/mount-targon/079694fdf251b5e7de788d9ab439d401d31ae160/img/champions/aurelion-sol/aurelion-sol-splash-fallback.jpg" alt="Aurelion Sol" width="300" height="200"></a>
  <div class="desc">Aurelion Sol, the Star Forger</div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="galerija">
  <a target="_blank" href="https://assets.vg247.com/current//2015/09/league_of_legnds_azir.jpg">
  <img src="https://assets.vg247.com/current//2015/09/league_of_legnds_azir.jpg" alt="Azir" width="300" height="200"></a>
  <div class="desc">Azir, the Emperor of the Sands</div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="galerija">
  <a target="_blank" href="http://news.cdn.leagueoflegends.com/public/images/pages/2015/breveal/img/Bard_Splash_WP.jpg">
  <img src="http://news.cdn.leagueoflegends.com/public/images/pages/2015/breveal/img/Bard_Splash_WP.jpg" alt="Bard" width="300" height="200"></a>
  <div class="desc">Bard, the Wandering Caretaker</div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="galerija">
  <a target="_blank" href="http://static.lolskill.net/img/skins/1215/blitzcrank_0.jpg">
  <img src="http://static.lolskill.net/img/skins/1215/blitzcrank_0.jpg" alt="Blitzcrank" width="300" height="200"></a>
  <div class="desc">Blitzcrank, the Great Steam Golem</div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="galerija">
  <a target="_blank" href="http://ddragon.leagueoflegends.com/cdn/img/champion/splash/Brand_0.jpg">
  <img src="http://ddragon.leagueoflegends.com/cdn/img/champion/splash/Brand_0.jpg" alt="Brand" width="300" height="200"></a>
  <div class="desc">Brand, the Burning Vengeance</div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="galerija">
  <a target="_blank" href="http://na.leagueoflegends.com/sites/default/files/styles/scale_xlarge/public/upload/b-splash.jpg?itok=vJzNVWjn">
  <img src="http://na.leagueoflegends.com/sites/default/files/styles/scale_xlarge/public/upload/b-splash.jpg?itok=vJzNVWjn" alt="Braum" width="300" height="200"></a>
  <div class="desc">Braum, the Heart of the Freljord</div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="galerija">
  <a target="_blank" href="https://img.clipartfox.com/5633c6d56bed03beb9292dd8c7f26199_-league-of-legends-and-caitlyn-league-of-legends-clipart_1215-717.jpeg">
  <img src="https://img.clipartfox.com/5633c6d56bed03beb9292dd8c7f26199_-league-of-legends-and-caitlyn-league-of-legends-clipart_1215-717.jpeg" alt="Caitlyn" width="300" height="200"></a>
  <div class="desc">Caitlyn, the Sheriff of Piltover</div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="galerija">
  <a target="_blank" href="http://ddragon.leagueoflegends.com/cdn/img/champion/splash/Camille_0.jpg">
  <img src="http://ddragon.leagueoflegends.com/cdn/img/champion/splash/Camille_0.jpg" alt="Camille" width="300" height="200"></a>
  <div class="desc">Camille, the Steel Shadow</div>
  </div>
  
  </body>
  
  </html>
```

Comment: You want us to make an image gallery for you?

Comment: No, just a little help how should I do it...

Comment: use a lightbox plugin. Google for "lightbox", there are plenty of solutions available - all using javascript, but more or less pre-written to a great extent

Answer (score 0):

You need to search for a *lightbox gallery* JavaScript plugin.There's a lot of them out there.

The one used on the example you gave is named **Colorbox**. Here you'll find more information about it: http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox/

Colorbox is based on jQuery library, so you'll need to use booth.

If you only need the gallery and you dont want to use jQuery you can give a try to **jsLightbox** http://jslightbox.felixhagspiel.de/ which is a pure JavaScript based gallery.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a crude looking but functional example of a image gallery that pops up in a modal:

```js
var images = $('.slideshow img');
var numImages = $('.slideshow img').length - 1;
var modalButton = $('.modal-button');
var prev = $('.prev');
var next = $('.next');
var num = 0;


modalButton.on('click', function() {
  $('.slideshow').toggleClass('active');
})

prev.on('click', function() {
  images.removeClass('active');
  num--;
  if (num < 0) {
    num = numImages;
  }
  images.eq(num).addClass('active');
});

next.on('click', function() {
  images.removeClass('active');
  num++;
  if (num > numImages) {
    num = 0;
  }
  images.eq(num).addClass('active');
});
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.content {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1024px;
  min-height: 100vh;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: gray;
}

.modal-button {
  padding: 10px;
  position: relative;
  border: 2px solid green;
  background-color: #fff;
  z-index: 3;
}

.modal-button:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.slideshow {
  display: none;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  margin: auto;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  z-index: 2;
}

.slideshow.active {
  display: flex;
}

.image-container {
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.image-container img {
  display: none;
}

.image-container img.active {
  display: inline;
}

.slideshow-controls {
  width: 350px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: tomato;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section class="content">
  <a class="modal-button">Click here to toggle slideshow</a>
  <section class="slideshow">
    <div class="image-container">
      <img class="active" src="http://placehold.it/350x350/000/bae">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/250x150/fff/58b">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/350x200/333/aeb">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/400x150/666/33c">
    </div>
    <div class="slideshow-controls">
      <button class="prev">Prev</button>
      <button class="next">Next</button>
    </div>
  </section>
</section>
```